# remove active class of filter item when another filter is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some javascript to filter products. At first the "All" option is selected. 
This is the html for the filter dropdown:

```
<div class="filter tags Filter-1" id="filter-1">
  <span class="filter-label">Filter 1</span>
  <div class="filter-list">
    <div class="all filter-item active"><a href="#" title="">All </a></div>
    <div class="filter1 filter-item item-2"><a href="#" title="Remove tag Filter 1">Filter1</a></div>
    <div class="filter2 filter-item item-2"><a href="#" title="Remove tag Filter 2">Filter2</a></div>
    <div class="filter3 filter-item item-2"><a href="#" title="Remove tag Filter 3">Filter 3</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(function() {
  var popped = ('state' in window.history && window.history.state !== null),
    initialURL = location.href;

  //function to handle the scenarios where back and forward buttons used in browser
  $(window).bind("popstate", function(e) {
    // Ignore inital popstate that some browsers fire on page load
    var initialPop = !popped && location.href == initialURL;
    popped = true;
    if (initialPop) {
      return;
    }
    ajaxLoadPage(location.href);
  });

  //the ajax function that does the AJAX calls to get the products and load them into the grid
  var ajaxLoadPage = function(url) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      data: {},
      complete: function(data) {
        $('#collection').html($("#collection", data.responseText).html());
        history.pushState({
          page: url
        }, url, url);
      }
    });
  }

  { % capture pathUrl %
  } { %
    if collection.handle %
  } { % capture url %
  }
  /collections/ {
    {
      collection.handle
    }
  } { % endcapture %
  } {
    {
      url
    }
  } { % elsif collection.all_products_count > 0 and collection.products.first.type == collection.title %
  } {
    {
      link_to_type
    }
  } { % elsif collection.all_products_count > 0 and collection.products.first.vendor == collection.title %
  } {
    {
      link_to_vendor
    }
  } { % endif %
  } { % endcapture %
  }

  var collectionUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '{{ pathUrl}}';

  //this detects one of the filters being clicked that should then
  //decide what URL to call in order to get the newly filtered product grid
  $("#filter-1 .filter-list .filter-item a, #filter-2 .filter-list .filter-item a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var self = this;

    // check if the click is on a "remove tag" filter
    var isRemoveFilter = false;
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
      $(this).removeAttr('title');
      isRemoveFilter = true;
    } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass("all")) {
      //check if "all brands" or "all colors" clicked
      var ul = $(this).parent().parent();
      $('.filter-item', ul).removeClass('active');
      $('.filter-item a', ul).removeAttr('title');
      isRemoveFilter = true;
    } else {
      //otherwise it means click on an unfiltered tag
      //remove other "Remove tag" in same filter row
      var ul = $(this).parent().parent();
      $('.filter-item', ul).removeClass('active');
      $('.all.filter-item', ul).removeClass('active');
      $('.filter-item a', ul).removeAttr('title');

      //add the active tag onto the new filter that was clicked
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      $(this).attr('title', 'Remove tag ' + $(this).text());
    }

    var activeBrand = '';
    if ($('#filter-1 ul .filter-item.active a').length > 0) {
      activeBrand = $('#filter-1 .filter-list .filter-item.active a').text();
    }
    var activeColor = '';
    if ($('#filter-2 ul .filter-item.active a').length > 0) {
      activeColor = $('#filter-2 .filter-list .filter-item.active a').text();
    }

    var selectedBrand = '';
    if ($(this).parents().hasClass('brands') && !isRemoveFilter) {
      selectedBrand = $(this).text();
    }
    var selectedColor = '';
    if ($(this).parents().hasClass('colors') && !isRemoveFilter) {
      selectedColor = $(this).text();
    }

    //console.log('activeBrand = ' + activeBrand);
    //console.log('activeColor = ' + activeColor);
    //console.log('selectedBrand = ' + selectedBrand);
    //console.log('selectedColor = ' + selectedColor);

    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    var newBrand = selectedBrand || activeBrand;
    var newColor = selectedColor || activeColor;
    //console.log('newBrand = ' + newBrand);
    //console.log('newColor = ' + newColor);

    url = collectionUrl + "/";

    if (newBrand != '' && newColor != '') {
      url += newBrand + "+" + newColor;
    } else if (newColor != '') {
      url += newColor;
    } else if (newBrand != '') {
      url += newBrand;
    }
    //console.log(url);
    ajaxLoadPage(url);

  });

});
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is when another element is selected which isn't the "All" filter, it needs to remove the .active class from the "All" filter.
As you can see I've tried using this:

```
 $('.all.filter-item', ul).removeClass('active');
```

But it doesn't remove the class. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the `all` class or is there any other action to do?

Comment: Just remove the active class from the all div